# Is there a differnt way of writing this code such that it doesn't use a loop

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, io, while-loop

I am trying to append a string I get from my client program. However I made it so that the append statement is in a while loop. This however affects the program, by not sending the message REALTIME onto the JTextArea.

How can I make the program such that it will not use a while loop or for loop and continue to accept messages from the client and output it to the textarea in real time? Perhaps just an if statement?

while loop area

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
```

For areas like

```
   tfFIXMsg.append( inputLine + "\n\n\n");
```

and

```
       tfCSVLine.append(outputLine+"\n\n\n");
```

It will not show the message on the textArea UNTIL the while loop is done. 
How can I make it so that it will continue to recieve messages from client, and be able to output it onto the textArea in realtime

```
try {
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
          { 
           System.out.println ("Server: " + inputLine); 


           tfFIXMsg.append( inputLine + "\n\n\n");


           int pos = inputLine.indexOf(inputLine, 0);
           h.addHighlight(50, 60, DefaultHighlighter.DefaultPainter);



           if (inputLine.trim().equals("Bye.")) {
               System.out.println("Exit program"); 
               break;
               } 

           Scanner input1 = new Scanner(new File(csvName));
           Scanner input2 = new Scanner(new File(csvName));
           Scanner input3 = new Scanner(new File(csvName));
           Scanner input4 = new Scanner(new File(csvName));


           String csvline = getCsvLineVal (getLocation34CSV(getTag34Value(Tag34Location(getTagCSV( parseFixMsg(inputLine ,inputLine))), getValueCSV( parseFixMsg(inputLine ,inputLine))), getVal34(input1,  input2)), getCSVLine( input3,  input4) );
           outputLine = compareClientFixCSV( getTagCSV( parseFixMsg(inputLine ,inputLine)), getValueCSV(parseFixMsg(inputLine ,inputLine)), getCSVTag(csvline), getCSVValue(csvline));

           out.println(outputLine);
           tfCSVLine.append(outputLine+"\n\n\n");

           input1.close();
           input2.close();
           input3.close();
           input4.close();



          }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your code is being processed on the UI thread.  The UI thread is what updates and renders your screen. As you've a while loop running on the UI thread, the UI cannot update. Its busy running your while loop.

The answer is to start another thread to do your processing.  Then, use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to get back onto the UI thread, and update your textbox. This is necessary because you shouldn't update UI objects off the UI thread.

Here's a [tutorial to get you started](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). It will explain this more thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

Updating the UI should happen in the AWT thread:

```java
out.println(outputLine);
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
      tfCSVLine.append(outputLine+"\n\n\n");
    }
});
```